# How to set counter size (total number of read lines) while reading large dataset using con in R

Tags: r, connection

In the code below, I am using `con` to read through large data matrix files (`sample.files`). This loop reads through all the lines in a chunk as it loops over each `sample.files`. Is there a way to set this loop in such a way that once it reads certain number of lines (say 500,000lines) as it loops over any number of files to get that many lines (i.e. counting all the chunks), then execute `Do this job` part? Can anyone please suggest how to do this?

```
for (isamp in 1:length(sample.files)){
con <- file(sample.files[isamp], open="r")  # close(con)
num.lines<-1 # so does while llop at least once
reads<-max.reads  
counter<- -1
while (num.lines >0){
counter<-counter+1
print(paste0("Reading chunk))

if(counter==0){
mydata<-try(scan(con,what=character(num.vars),skip=(reads*counter)+skip.lines,nlines=reads,sep="\t",fill=TRUE,na.strings="",quote="\""))
}else{
mydata<-try(scan(con,what=character(num.vars),nlines=reads,sep="\t",fill=TRUE,na.strings="",quote="\""))
}


num.lines<-length(mydata)/(num.vars)
print(num.lines)
if(num.lines==0){next}
dim(mydata)<-c(num.vars,num.lines)
mydata<-t(mydata)
colnames(mydata)<-column.labels

If (total accumulated rows are 500,000 line){
'Do this job'
}
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly... about your question, maybe I didn't understand you completely but couldn't you just put another counter outside the first for-loop ? (pretty similar to what you're doing with counter variable outside while-loop)